# Predicate not being applied in LinqToExcel query

Tags: c#, linq-to-excel

I have come across the [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) library and have been playing around with it a bit. I seem to be mis-understanding how the querying works. I have created a simple worksheet with some customer info. Using LinqPad, I've setup my query as so:

```cs
void Main()
{
    string path = @"E:\Documents\LINQPad\LINQPad Queries\LinqToExcel\Customers.xlsx";

    var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(path);

    // Mappings and Transforms:
    excel.AddMapping<Customer>(c => c.Contact, "Contact Person");
    excel.AddMapping<Customer>(c => c.CompanyName, "Company Name");
    excel.AddMapping<Customer>(c => c.IsPreferred, "Preferred");
    excel.AddTransformation<Customer>(c => c.IsPreferred, cellValue => cellValue == "Yes");

    // Query:
    var preferrdCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet<Customer>("Customers")
                            where c.IsPreferred  // this has no effect?
                            orderby c.CompanyName
                            select new { c.CompanyName, c.Contact, c.IsPreferred };

    // Display:
    preferrdCompanies.Dump("Preferred Customers:");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Customer
{
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsPreferred { get; set; }   
}
```

For some reason, the predicate is not being applied. The transform to **true**(bool) from the text "Yes" is working. If I write:

```cs
preferrdCompanies.ToList().Where(c => c.IsPreferred).Dump("Preferred Customers:");
```

I get the filtered list as you would expect. I've been looking for a simple error in my code but it throws no exceptions and I can't find anything obviously wrong, so I guess I just don't understand how the querying functions?

Any answer/explanation would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If adding `ToList` before `Where` works then it's likely a bug in LinqToExcel.

Comment: That could be; I added ToList() to change the result set from an ExcelQueryable<> to a List<> just to get the filtered results. It acts as if the ExcelQueryable has a method to accept a predicate but does nothing with it.

Comment: Possible; or there's a bug in the parsing that doesn't process a boolean column properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try explicitly setting `c.IsPreferred == true` in the where clause and see if that resolves your issue.

```
var preferrdCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet<Customer>("Customers")
                        where c.IsPreferred == true
                        orderby c.CompanyName
                        select new { c.CompanyName, c.Contact, c.IsPreferred };
```

Comment: Oddly, if I add c.IsPreferred == true (or false), it simply returns a collection with no items.